# Ruby on rails undefined variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a new app and used an old app as kind of a reference on how to do things I am creating the new page and using the form_for

```
<% form_for(store) do |f| %>

<% end %>


def new
  @store = Store.new
end
```

Above is my controller did it the same way I did in my last app and getting this error. I am getting this error that is puzzling me because it works on other applications I made.

```
undefined local variable or method `store' for #<#<Class:0x007fb26b3634c0>:0x007fb26a427ce0>
Did you mean?  @store
```

I must be missing something conceptually.

Answer (score 5):

You created variable `@store`, that's why ruby doesn't know what is `store`

```
<% form_for(@store) do |f| %>
```

You should read error messages

> undefined local variable or method `store' ... Did you mean?  @store

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing something simple...

there was a change in the recent version of rails that passes a local variable to the partial that contains the form_for... and in doing so, removes the need for the @ symbol in the partial view. You can fix your error by adding an @ symbol before the store in the form for, or by creating the "translation" of the global variable to the local one... (excuse the terminology, i'm self taught).

```
<%= render 'form', store: @store %>
```

Comment: So I must not be using the same versions of rails?

Comment: you are using examples that were generated by different versions of rails, that have a subtle difference... it doesn't really have to do with being different versions though, just a new "normal" way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Use `@store` in view.

```
<% form_for(@store) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```